# change images in my webpage on a particular time interval in php

Tags: php, image

I created a database for storing the image path and actual image is store in the directory. 
Then i want to set a time interval in hour for changing the image randomly inmy webpage(eg: 24 hrs is the time interval i given the image will be changed on every day 12:00) and if i give 12 hrs interval the image change happends in every 12 hrs in a day.

I already made a form to submiting the value for time interval. i have only time interval in hours.

How can be do this in PHP.?.I want to do this change in my server side.. i am new to php

Please give me an example code for doing this .

Thanks.

Comment: "I already made a form to submiting the value for time interval"

show it to us :)

Comment: you can use javascript setinterval() for this

Comment: @sujith Agarwal<html>
  <body>
     <form method="post" action="display_test.php">
  Enter the interval in hrs <input type="text" name="interval" />
  
  <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>

Comment: just write a program for displaying the images normally , Shall i show my code

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: '$query="select * from imgtables  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";


$q1= mysql_query($query,$sp);
if($q1==FALSE ){

   die(mysql_error());
    }
 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1)){
 
  $str="gallery/".$row['imgurl'];
  echo '<img src="'.$str.'" width=100px height=50px>'; 
  
  }
 
              }
  mysql_close($sp);
  '

Comment: Hello Khushboo I just past my code for displaying the image. I dont't know how to set the time interval in the execution of the php code

Comment: just a quick ref link.. you may find this useful https://github.com/dcondrey/moody-wp

Comment: @user3789039 : Don't post your code in comment, edit your question and add it, it will be simpler to read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `setInterval(abc, 1000);`1000 value as per your time.
and `#divname` is id of div in which you want to display the image

```
    function abc() {
      jQuery.ajax({
                url:'random_image.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:'',
                success:function(results){
                    jQuery("#divname").html(results);

                }
            });
      }

abc();
setInterval(abc, 1000);
```

In random_image.php

```
$query="select * from imgtables ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 "; 
$q1= mysql_query($query,$sp); 
if($q1==FALSE ){ die(mysql_error()); } 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1)){ 
$str="gallery/".$row['imgurl']; echo '<img src="'.$str.'" width=100px height=50px>'; } 
} 
mysql_close($sp);
```

Comment: Hello Khushboo is there any method to implement this without using the jquery/Ajax i mean by using php code , I give the time interval as input from a form..

Comment: I need to change image in the server itself ,Not by sending a request from client.